# unable to animate in highchart table

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using the highcharts table plugin for displaying charts, but I'm struggling to animate them. I'm pulling data from my action and displaying it using iterators. As I'm new to this technology I'm unable to find anything that can help. Thanks in Advance

JSP calling an action:

```
$("#management").click( function() {
    $.ajax( {
        url : 'ManagementAction.html',
        type : 'POST',
        data : { },
        dataType: "html",
        success : function(html) {
            $('#response').html(html);
        },
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('An error occurred! ' + thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

JSP with the highcharts table:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Low Priority Sla</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <s:iterator var="var" value="totalResultOfManagement" status="rights">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <s:property value="key"/>
            </td>
            <s:iterator value="value" var="ctr">
                <td data-graph-item-color="green">
                    <s:property value="#ctr"/>
                </td>
            </s:iterator>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please add a sample of your code (for example on jsfiddle.net)

Comment: On a page resize? There is a parameter doAnimate for a lot of functions e.g. graph.setSize(width,height, doAnimation = true);

Comment: Actually i'm using 2 jsp's in one jsp i'm calling an action using below code$("#management").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : 'ManagementAction.html', 
    type : 'POST', 
    data : { 
      
       }, 
    dataType: "html",
    success : function(html) {
    $('#response').html(html);  
     
    },
    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
     alert('An error occurred! ' + thrownError);
    }
   
   });    
  });

Comment: In another jsp i'm using highchart Table <thead>
        <tr>  <th></th>
         <th > Low Priority Sla</th>
                  </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
     <s:iterator var="var" value="totalResultOfManagement" status="rights">
         <tr>
             <td><s:property value="key"/></td>
    <s:iterator value="value" var="ctr">       <td data-graph-item-color="green"><s:property value="#ctr"/></td>            </s:iterator>
   </tr>    </s:iterator>
         </tbody>

Comment: In my first jsp i have something like this <div id="response"></div>